# How can I slice an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arguments, slice

I was trying to slice an object using Array.prototype, but it returns an empty array, is there any method to slice objects besides passing arguments or is just my code that has something wrong? Thx!!

```
var my_object = {
 0: 'zero',
 1: 'one',
 2: 'two',
 3: 'three',
 4: 'four'
};

var sliced = Array.prototype.slice.call(my_object, 4);
console.log(sliced);
```

Comment: Closest you can get to that is deleting the key with `delete object.property` and making sure you've stored that property in a separate variable before then.

Comment: What is your expected output? Slicing an object makes no sense - it doesn't mean anything, but if you can explain what you'd like your expected output to be we can work to get there.

Comment: I try to create a new array, only with the properties that I could need,
i.e:

var obj = {car: 'audi', engine: 'diesel', color: 'blue'}

as output I would like a new object only with the "color" property.

Comment: *I would like a new object* - but `Array.slice` returns an array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I was trying to slice an object using `Array.prototype`, but it returns an empty array

That's because it doesn't have a `.length` property. It will try to access it, get `undefined`, cast it to a number, get `0`, and slice at most that many properties out of the object. To achieve the desired result, you therefore have to assign it a `length`, or iterator through the object manually:

```js
var my_object = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four'};

my_object.length = 5;
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(my_object, 4));

var sliced = [];
for (var i=0; i<4; i++)
    sliced[i] = my_object[i];
console.log(sliced);
```

Comment: so I guess there's no other way than manually modifying the object, adding length, or the iterator...

Comment: Don't be fooled, keep reading as @trad now has the best answer, and a couple other clever answers can be found.

Answer (score 72):

Nobody mentioned [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) yet, which might be the most flexible way to do it.  This method uses the same ordering as `for..in` when enumerating properties, i.e. the order that properties were originally entered in the object.  You also get subarrays with both property and value so you can use whichever or both.  Finally you don't have to worry about the properties being numerical or setting an extra length property (as you do when using `Array.prototype.slice.call()`).
Here's an example:

```
const obj = {'prop1': 'foo', 'prop2': 'bar', 'prop3': 'baz', 'prop4': {'prop': 'buzz'}};
```

You want to slice the first two values:

```
Object.entries(obj).slice(0,2).map(entry => entry[1]);
//["foo", "bar"]
```

All of the keys?

```
Object.entries(obj).slice(0).map(entry => entry[0]);
//["prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop4"]
```

The last key-value pair?

```
Object.entries(obj).slice(-1)
//[ ['prop4', {'prop': 'buzz'}] ]
```

Comment: `Object.entries` is certainly a useful method to know about (new with ECMA 262, apparently) ... but it seems just to produce an array of arrays, which isn't really what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Object.entries is not supported in IE.

Comment: Unfortunately This solution will result in a new Array and not a new Object. When we want to slice an Object, we expect a sliced Object and not a sliced Array.

Comment: I love you for this answer @Trad

Answer (score 37):

You can `reduce` the result of `Object.keys` function

```js
const myObject = {
 0: 'zero',
 1: 'one',
 2: 'two',
 3: 'three',
 4: 'four'
};

const sliced = Object.keys(myObject).slice(0, 2).reduce((result, key) => {
                    result[key] = myObject[key];

                    return result;
                }, {});

console.log(sliced);
```

Comment: best one! love it.

Answer (score 37):

The best modern solution to this is the combination of **Object.fromEntries** and **Object.entries**.

```js
const foo = {
    one: 'ONE',
    two: 'TWO',
    three: 'THREE',
    four: 'FOUR',
}

const sliced = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(foo).slice(1, 3)
)

console.log(sliced)
```

Comment: I'm curious, did you benchmark this against other methods? Istinctively seems slow but I might be wrong. It's definitely the most elegant solution imho.

Comment: I haven't tested it. My guess is my solution is a little bit slower but the accepted answer is not returning the keys and is not very clean in my opinion.

Comment: Nice solution, v clean

Answer (score 5):

```
var obj = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four'};
var result = Object.keys(obj).slice(0,2).map(key => ({[key]:obj[key]}));

console.log(result);
```

> [ { '0': 'zero' }, { '1': 'one' } ]

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a 'length' property to `my_object` and then your code should work:

```js
    var my_object = {
     0: 'zero',
     1: 'one',
     2: 'two',
     3: 'three',
     4: 'four',
     length: 5
    };
    
    var sliced = Array.prototype.slice.call(my_object, 4);
    console.log(sliced);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(my_object).slice(0,4));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it can helps you:

```
var my_object = { 0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four' };

var sliced = Object.keys(my_object).map(function(key) { return my_object[key] }).slice(4);

console.log(sliced);
```

Comment: with the downside that `keys()` is not guaranteed to return the keys for the object in any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless it has a <s>`[Symbol.iterator]` generator function and</s> `length` property exists. Such as;

```js
var my_object = { 0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', length:5 },
       sliced;

my_object[Symbol.iterator] = function* (){
                                          var oks = Object.keys(this);
                                          for (var key of oks) yield this[key];
                                         };

sliced = Array.prototype.slice.call(my_object, 2);
console.log(sliced);
```

Comment: An iterator *or* a length is enough, you don't need both.

Comment: @Bergi That's what i had thought about having just an iterator... i've just tested with an iterator an it didn't work.. I am not sure with only `length` property it would be OK though. No just an iterator won't cut. May be there is something i am missing.

Comment: `slice` doesn't care for an iterator (it only cares for the length), `Array.from(my_object).slice(4)` would. I thought you had `Array.from` in mind when talking about iterables…

Comment: @Bergi try it with `.slice(2)`

Comment: @Bergi OK you are right with only `length` property it's fine. Gotto correct.

Comment: Btw, in your generator function you really should use a simple `for in` enumeration instead of making the detour via `Object.keys`

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention it in your question, but that looks awfully a lot like an arguments object.

Convert it to an array using `Array.from()` then use it like any other array. As long as it is an enumerable object.

For a polyfill for older browsers, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Works, but acts weird when things get serious
// Avoids screwing with the properties of my_object
// You don't get Object.create() until ES5.1
function lazySlice(obj, idx) {
  var newObj = Object.create(obj, { length: {value: Object.keys(obj).length} }),
  idx = idx || 0;

  return Array.prototype.slice.call(newObj, idx);
}

// Only gives you own enumerable properties with keys "0" to n
// Preserves element order (based on key number)
// Ignores non-numbered keys
// You don't get Object.keys() until ES5
function enumSlice(obj, idx) {
  var arr = [], 
    keys = Object.keys(obj),
    idx = idx || 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= keys.length - 1; i++)
    if (keys[i] >= idx && keys[i] % 1 === 0 && keys[i] >= 0 && keys[i].indexOf('e') < 0) 
      arr.push(obj[keys[i]]);

  return arr;
}

var my_object = {
  0: 'zero',
  1: 'one',
  2: 'two',
  3: 'three',
  4: 'four'
}; 
console.log(lazySlice(my_object, 3));      // [ 'three', 'four' ]
console.log(enumSlice(my_object, 3));      // [ 'three', 'four' ]

var mixed_object = {
   "9": 'nine',
   "2": 'two',
   "1": 'one',
   "7": 'seven',
   "7.5": 'seven point five',
   "1e4": 'sneaky',
   "-4": 'negative four',
   "0": 'zero',
   "length": 35
};
console.log(lazySlice(mixed_object));      // [ 'zero', 'one', 'two', , , , , 'seven',  ]
console.log(enumSlice(mixed_object));      // [ 'zero', 'one', 'two', 'seven', 'nine' ]
```