# Use slice on javascript object to loop for all elements except first two?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object of objects and I'd like to use a v-for loop to llop through all the objects except the first two ones, sadly I can't use slice sice it's only for arrays, is it possible to remove the first wo elements of an object using javascript without creating a new object

My object is something like:

```
{
    First: { },
    Second: { },
    Third: { }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new object?

Comment: You can use index and skip the starting two indexes

Comment: See this <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <span>{{ index }}</span>
</div> . Have a if condition and if index ===1 || index===2 dont do anything

Answer (score 0):

I am not that pro in js but first check this url

[How to loop through a plain JavaScript object with the objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-a-plain-javascript-object-with-the-objects-as-members)

this just to get maybe an idea

[How can I slice an object in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336556/how-can-i-slice-an-object-in-javascript)

so I will give you a logic where you may get a solution
if you won't get answer from above
when finished from url and get clear understand

create a function where it iterate over objects
from what I suggest

then create a variable =1
if var_inc==1 or var-==2
continue
else
do whatever

then do a for loop to loop over over objects
then do that function
just get the logic maybe you get it..

❤

Answer (score 0):

JS objects don't store the order of elements like arrays. In the general case, there is no such thing as order of specific key-value pairs. However, you can iterate through object values using some utility libraries (like underscore https://underscorejs.org/#pairs), or you could just use raw js to do something this:

```js
// this will convert your object to an array of values with arbitrary order
Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key])

// this will sort keys alphabetically
Object.keys(obj).sort().map(key => obj[key])
```

Note that some browsers can retain order of keys when calling `Object.keys()` but you should not rely on it, because it isn't guaranteed.
I would suggest to just use array of objects to be sure of order like this:

```js
[{ key: "First", value: 1 }, { key: "Second", value: 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete the properties of the objects then you can use *delete* keyword.

```
delete Obj['First']
delete Obj['Second']`
```

This would delete both the keys and object would have only 'Third' key